# how to see logs like the Log.info("something") in test kitchen?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

i did this but its not showing any log on the console even after running

```
kitchen test -l info
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-l` on the command line sets the log level for kitchen itself, not Chef. That is controlled via the `log_level` key in your provisioned config section.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the info coderanger but is there any way I can see Chef.Log.info's output in the kitchen logs?

Comment: All output from the provisioner ends up in the Kitchen output, and all output from Kitchen ends up in the instance log.